# Regex to select *.aspx until something different from a-z

Tags: c#, regex

I have something like this string:

```
string s = "Q.ROOT_PATH + 'pgs/ChangePassword.aspx?a=5'";
```

I want to get the words before `.aspx` until find the character different of a-z, Result:

```
"ChangePassword.aspx"
```

My Regex:

```
[a-z](.aspx)
```

What else i need to do?

Comment: Your requirement is a bit strange, but possible with C# regex. Try `Regex.Match(input, @"\P{L}(.*?\.aspx)", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Groups[1].Value`. But if the file name always starts after `/` you can use `@"/(.*?)\.aspx"` and again access the group 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could certainly use regular expression to handle this, you might consider some of the built-in functions within .NET that can already handle this for you. I'll provide two examples for how to resolve this (with and without regular expressions).

**Using The [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) Method**

The `System.IO` namespace actually exposes a method called `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` that will handle this exact operation for you :

```
// This will find the file mentioned in the path and return it without
// an extension ("pgs/ChangePassword.aspx?a=5" > "ChangePassword")
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(input);
```

You can [see this approach here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uphetG).

**Via a Regular Expression**

You can accomplish this through a lookahead which will match a string of one or more letters `[a-zA-Z]+` that precede an `.aspx` using the [`Regex.Match()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
// This will match any set of alphabetical characters that appear before
// an '.aspx' ("pgs/ChangePassword.aspx?a=5" > "ChangePassword")
var fileName = Regex.Match(input,@"[a-zA-Z]+(?=\.aspx)");
```

You can [see a working example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/phnQOO).

Comment: Or with a capturing group if we take up this approach.